# isspace not working correctly?

Tags: c, file, ctype

It is probably my code that's not working, but any white-space characters (\n, \t, \r, etc.) are not being converted to a space " ". As far as I can see, it looks like it should work, but it seg faults each time it hits a new line.

Edit: Sorry, It does change white-space characers to ' ', but it stops after the new line is hit. The program then runs through the code until that new line spot -- where it seg faults.

<strike>It also will not replace any of the white-spaces.</strike> The code draws in a .txt file, so if you want to run it, make a text file named alice.txt (or you can change the code) and include space characters in the file.

Can you please help me, I've been trying to solve this for hours with no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 4096

void upper(char *tok, FILE *out);
void rstrip(char *tok, FILE *out);

int main ()
{
    char *tok;  //tokenizer
    char buf[LEN];
    FILE *in = fopen("alice.txt", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    int len = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, LEN, in)) {
        /* cleans all line breaks, tabs, etc, into space*/
        while (buf[len]) {
            printf("%c", buf[len]); //Error checking, prints each char of buf
            if (isspace(buf[len]))  //isspace not working properly? not changing \t, \r, etc to ' ' */
                buf[len] = ' ';     //not replacing
            if (buf[len] < 0)   //added cuz negative character values were being found in text file.
                buf[len] = ' '; 
            len++;
        }

        /*parses by words*/
        tok = strtok(buf, " ");
        rstrip(tok, out);
        while (tok != NULL) {
            tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
            rstrip(tok, out);
        }
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0; 
}

/*makes appropiate words uppercase*/
void upper(char *tok, FILE *out)
{
    int cur = strlen(tok) - 1; //current place

    while (cur >= 0) {
        tok[cur] = toupper(tok[cur]);
        printf("%s\n", tok); 
        fprintf(out, "%s", tok);
        cur--;
    }

}

/*checks for 'z' in tok (the word)*/
void rstrip(char *tok, FILE *out)
{
    int cur = strlen(tok) - 1; //current place

    printf("%s", tok);
    while (cur >= 0) {
        if (tok[cur] == 'z')
            upper(tok, out);
        cur--;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should intialise variable len back to 0 after first loop. Also start using debugger

Comment: Your second `strtok` (the one with the `NULL`) should be *after* the `rstrip` call, otherwise you're skipping the first token (and not terminating the loop properly). And `isspace` is working perfectly. The causes of any problems you're having are elsewhere.

Comment: `if (buf[len] < 0)` this can only happen if `FILE *in = fopen("alice.txt", "r");` failed. Validate that the file is open before reading. (e.g. `if (!in) { printf ("error: open failed\n"; return 1; }`. That will prevent **strange** characters from being read from a text file. Do the same for `out` before writing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I'm not sure about that one. If your machine uses signed chars, there might well be negative entries in `buf`. All UTF-8 sequences that don't represent ASCII will be made up of negative signed chars. (They should be repesented as `uint8_t`, of course.) In Latin1, the negative characters aren't called _strange_, they are called _accented_.

Comment: OK, I'll give you that one. I was considering that `alice.txt` would contain standard ASCII text. If `alice.txt` is UTF-8, then that assumption needs reconsidering. If we know what was in `alice.txt` then we would know for sure. However, none of that makes the validation recommendations any less correct.

Answer (score 1):

You set `len = 0;` in the wrong place.

You need:

```
while (fgets(buf, LEN, in) != 0)
{
    for (int len = 0; buf[len] != '\0'; len++)
    {
        printf("%c", buf[len]);
        if (isspace((unsigned char)buf[len]))
            buf[len] = ' ';
        if (buf[len] < 0)
            buf[len] = ' ';
    }
    …rest of loop…
}
```

This ensures you set `len` to 0 for each line that is read.  You also need to ensure that the argument to `isspace()` is valid — that means it is an `int` and must either be EOF or the value corresponding to an `unsigned char`.

The C standard says (referring to the arguments for the `is*()` functions in `<ctype.h>`:

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro EOF.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Yeah; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to validating that your `FILE *streams` are open, you also need to validate values passed to your functions. When `strtok` completes tokenizing, it returns `NULL`. You do not want to pass `NULL` to `rstrip`. E.g:

```
void rstrip(char *tok, FILE *out)
{
    if (!tok) return;          // validate tok

    int cur = strlen(tok) - 1; //current place
```

You need to do the same for `upper`. Simply fixing those issues go a long way. After incorporating the validations and the changes suggested by J.L.:

**input:**

```
$ cat alice.txt
#include <stdio.h>
int func()
{
z z z z z
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",func());
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/ctypehelp
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>int func()
intfunc(){
{ z z z z z
zZ
zZ
zZ
zZ
zZ
}
}int main(void)
intmain(void){
{    printf("%d\n",func());
printf("%d\n",func());    return 0;
return0;}
```

**out.txt:**

```
$ cat out.txt
ZZZZZ
```

Work on these improvements and post back when you are stuck again.